# How do can I make Google Assistance give me news articles?

Tags: google-assistant

at the moment when I say "I want the latest news", Google Assistant reads back the news to me.

What I want is for it to give me the latest news (like what's available in Google News & Weather) in summary format and then I can choose what I want to read.

Is this possible? Thanks